# When I have click the button all the records in the table is displayed in the table

Tags: java, sql, database, sql-like

When I have click the button all the records in the table are displayed in the table. I have used like and equal operators in my sql query it does work in the second time first time all the data are retrieved to the table? Can anyone tell me whats wrong in the code?

```
 try{
            String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=gym2 ";
                String username = "mali";
                String password = "12345";
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement ();
                ResultSet rs;
                String empid =jLabel3.getText()+jTextField1.getText();
                String name = jTextField2.getText();
               // String d =jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
       String sql = "SELECT emp_id,firstname,designation,full_address,gender,land,monthly_sal FROM employee_reg where (emp_id = '"+empid+"' or firstname LIKE '"+name+"%')";


        rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            } 
        }
```

Comment: never do something like that: `catch(Exception e){

            }`. At least print the stacktrace and you will see what is going on

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Please edit your question, and make clear what you want. Maybe you can show us the table structure and some example entries.

Comment: Print the query that you are creating. System.out.println(sql); There may be chance in query at first time, the firstName will be empty. e.g. you query may be looks like                                                                     SELECT emp_id,firstname,designation,full_address,gender,land,monthly_sal FROM employee_reg where (emp_id = '2' or firstname LIKE ' %');     The LIKE '%' will fetch all the records.

Comment: so what sohould i do??

Comment: what should i do??

Comment: @AshanMalinda How should we know it, we do not know what you need

Comment: i dont want all the result set i want the specific result set which is filtered. when i first clicked it loads all the data and the i click again then it filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think "first time" and "second time" in the original question actually stands for "jTextField1 value defined" and "jTextField2 value defined".

Generated SQL query string with empty jTextField2 (name) would result in:

```
SELECT emp_id,firstname,designation,full_address,gender,land,monthly_sal
FROM employee_reg where (emp_id = '...' or firstname LIKE '%');
```

`firstname LIKE '%'` would match all records where firstname is not NULL and since conditions are separated by `OR` the `emp_id = '...'` condition would have very little effect.

To actually "use filters when present" scenario we need to exclude condition if corresponding field is blank:

```
String     url       = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=gym2 ";
String     username  = "mali";
String     password  = "12345";
Connection con       = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
Statement  st        = con.createStatement ();
ResultSet  rs;

// Prepare the whole emp_id condition string
String     empidCond = " or emp_id = '" + jLabel3.getText()+jTextField1.getText() + "'";
// Clear it if jTextField1 is empty
if(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()) {empidCond = "";}

// Prepare the whole firstname condition string
String     nameCond  = " or firstname LIKE '" + jTextField2.getText() + "%'";
// Clear it if jTextField2is empty
if(jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()) {nameCond = "";}
// String d          = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

// Create SQL statement with one "stub" condition always false
// to "chain" the other conditions to
String sql = "SELECT emp_id,firstname,designation,full_address,gender,land,monthly_sal "+
             "FROM employee_reg "+
             "WHERE 1=2" + empidCond + nameCond;

rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

I must note here that the whole thing is for educational purposes only and none of the code above should ever be used in production.